# Can you use WebAudioMidi to send midi notes to a DAW?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Can you use Javascript to send notes from the browser to a DAW (ableton, cubase etc)?

I'm thinking of writing a demo for webaudiomidi and want to have functions that generate midi notes that would be played by a VSTi in a DAW. Has anyone had a chance to try this?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this. All I needed was a virtual midi device created in OSX, and the browser just sends midi data to that virtual device, whilst the DAW was listening on the midi in from that virtual device